# Uploading png images to GCS in R - can upload individually, but cannot upload entire directory

Tags: r, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-storage-r

We have a local directory with 20000 images that needs to go to GCS. Using R (and `googleCloudStorageR`), we can loop over each of the images and upload to GCS as such:

```
# setup
library(googleCloudStorageR)
gcs_auth(json_file = 'my/gcs/admin/creds.json')
all_png_images <- list.files('../path/to/local-images/directory')

# and loop
for(i in 1:length(all_png_images)) {
    googleCloudStorageR::gcs_upload(
      file = paste0(base_url, all_png_images[i]),
      bucket = 'my-bucket',
      name = paste0('images-folder/', all_png_images[i]),
      predefinedAcl = 'default'
    )
}
```

and this works perfectly... however, it would be much better if I could simply point to the directory and upload all at once, rather than have to point to a directory and loop over each file. I have tried to use the `gcs_save_all` function, to no success:

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_save_all(
  directory = 'path-to-all-images',
  bucket = 'my-bucket'
)
```

throws the error `2020-10-01 16:23:47 -- File size detected as 377.1 Kb 2020-10-01 16:23:47> Request Status Code: 400 Error: API returned: Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access`

I am trying to find out why `gcs_save_all` is not working, or if there is another way I can do this in R.

Comment: Thanks this is a bug, will look into it.  https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR/issues/129

Comment: Should be fixed now if you install via `remotes::install_github("cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR")` will be on CRAN in the future v0.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in the library needs to be updated to support bucket level ACL, for now you can replicate its function to what it will be fixed to, by specifying "bucketLevel" ACL which is supported in `gcs_upload`

e.g.

```
gcs_save_all <- function(directory = getwd(),
                         bucket = gcs_get_global_bucket(),
                         pattern = ""){

  tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
  on.exit(unlink(tmp))

  bucket <- as.bucket_name(bucket)

  the_files <- list.files(path = directory,
                          all.files = TRUE,
                          recursive = TRUE,
                          pattern = pattern)
  
  withCallingHandlers(
    zip::zip(tmp, files = the_files),
    deprecated = function(e) NULL)

  # modified to accept ACL on bucket
  gcs_upload(tmp, bucket = bucket, name = directory, predefinedAcl = "bucketLevel")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR/issues/129) on googleCloudStorageR and they've fixed the problem in the latest version on GitHub, so updating to that will allow you to do this:

```
googleCloudStorageR::gcs_save_all(
  directory = 'path-to-all-images',
  bucket = 'my-bucket',
  predefinedAcl = "bucketLevel"
)
```

Original answer:

GCS has two ways of handling authorization for objects in a bucket: ACLs and IAM. In order to simplify and allow users to only worry about one authorization scheme, buckets can enable "uniform bucket-level access," which prevents the use of ACLs. Presumably, you have this feature enabled on your bucket.

When you set `predefinedAcl = 'default'`, you specified that GCS shouldn't do anything special with ACLs, which is the correct setting when uploading to a bucket with uniform bucket-level access.

It appears `gcs_save_all` does not have such a parameter, and the default value appears to be the predefined ACL "private," which is not a valid choice when uniform bucket-level access is enabled.